Determining the impedance and voltage source with lagging currents

I have the following system where I have to determine the impedance Z1. However the current flowing through this impedance flows after the current of 12A and I'm not sure on how to approach this problem. I tried doing a KCL analysis but I ended up with equations which didn't seem to make sense.
The equations I started off with where
$$ \frac{V_D-V_E}{(2+3j)}+\frac{V_D}{Z}+\frac{V_B}{31.83i}=0 $$
$$ \frac{V_B-V_D}{3}+\frac{V_B}{31.83i}=0 $$
$$ \frac{V_E-V_D}{(2+3j)}-\frac{V_D}{Z}+\frac{V_B}{31.83i}=0 $$
since
$$ V_D-V_B=30$$
I was able to simplify it too
$$ \frac{V_D-V_E}{(2+3j)}+\frac{V_D}{Z}+10=0 $$
$$ \frac{V_B-V_D}{3}+\frac{V_B}{31.83i}=0 $$
$$ \frac{V_E-V_D}{(2+3j)}-\frac{V_D}{Z}+10=0 $$
From these I was also able to determine that
$$V_B = 318,3i$$
and that
$$V_D = 320angle(-85)$$
When trying to solve the system further, since I have two unknowns and 2 equations, I ended up getting a wrong answer. I'd rather want to know if what I have so far is correct and if I am approaching this problem correctly.

please show us which equations don't make sense and how you ended up with them – how are we to help you avoid mistakes when we don't see where you're doing them?

@MarcusMüller My apologies, I didn't add my work because I was doing it on paper and was moreso looking for a general idea to apply. I haven't seen cases before where the question simply says "the current of 5A flows after that of the 12A" without giving the angle, so I wanted an suggestion to approach that. I have added my work.
